# display datalables on pie chart using HighCharts (data overlapping and overflowing)

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to display pie chart next to each other with data labels, but in few of the case the data lables are is getting overlap and in some cases data is not getting displayed not sure what changes should i make. Below is the image with issue

```
series:[
{
dataLabels:{
enabled:true,
padding:2,
formatter:function(){
return `10`
}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in an online editor with all the config? Because with the default settings, the date labels are not hidden when two pie series overlap: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0Lpkyw2r/